# How to delete a node missing a child with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, nodes

I'd like to remove nodes that lack a specific child.

For example, I would like to delete the second `<release>` node here:

```
<release>
 <artist>Johnny Cash</artist>
 <album>Live from Folsom Prison</album>
</release>
<release>
 <artist>Johnny Cash</artist>
</release>
```

I have tried: `doc.xpath("//Release[album='']").remove`, but that clearly doesn't work because I need to find the nodes where album doesn't exist and not where it's empty.

The alternative I would need would be to return something like "empty" for any node where album was not included when I run this command `albums= doc.search('release/album').map{ |t| t.text}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do:

```
doc.xpath('//release[not(album)]').remove
```

Comment: Nice shorthand, had no idea about not. Very useful

Comment: Thanks so much, very simple.  One more quick question if you have a moment, if I wanted to check for multiple children would I need to do individual lines of code, or is there an option like `doc.xpath('//release[not(album artist)]').remove`?

Comment: Should be: `//release[not(album) or not(artist)]` You can use `or` or `and`

Answer (score -1):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
node_set = doc.search('release')
del_node = node_set.select { |n| n.last_element_child.name != 'album'}.first
node_set.delete(del_node)
```

or

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//release').delete(doc.xpath('//release').last)
```

Comment: Use Nokogiri::XML with xml data.

Comment: @pguardiario Does it matter? what the advantages should I have with that? why it is not correct?

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, I did. But improvement suggestion is good, but not down-vote a working one.

Comment: I agree with that at least.